# exim4 on Debian: Forward all local mail

Tags: debian, exim

My goal is to forward all local mail on my servers to a specific mail address. I have set up Exim4 in a satellite configuration on Debian Wheezy, however, exim4 ignores wildcards in /etc/aliases:

```
*: mydestination@foobar.com
```

This wildcard is silently ignored by exim4. I could create hard-coded forwards, however, that's error-prone. I have no specific need for Exim4, however, I'd be interested in a solution which includes exim4, as it's installed on debian by default.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the lookup type in /etc/exim4/conf.d/router/400_exim4-config_system_aliases to use nwildlsearch instead of lsearch:

```
data = ${lookup{$local_part}nwildlsearch{/etc/aliases}}
```